# Border color to header without affect body

Tags: html, css

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6ycwt6k/)

I want to know how can I add a border to header without affect the body or vice-versa.

```css
.content-box {
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.content-box-header {
  background: #202020;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="max-width: 330px;">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="content-box-header">
      Chocolate Bar
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>PHP</li>
      <li>HTML</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like `border-top`, `border-right`, and `border-left`?

Comment: I tested this way already. Doesn't work. Because the content box is outside header, so if add a border to header i'll see the same result, because header will not overwrite the content-box border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break it up into more pieces. Below I broke it up into header, body, and the content box. From here, just assign one border to the body, and another to the header. Removing the border definition from the entire parent should fix it.

```css
.cbox-body {
  background: #ebebeb;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
.content-box-header {
  background: #202020;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
#content{
  max-width:330px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="content-box-header">
      <p>Chocolate Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cbox-body">
      <ul>
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>HTML</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the border for header class,

```
  .content-box {
      background: #ebebeb; 
      border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  }

  .content-box-header {
      border: 1px solid #colorcode;
      background: #202020;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
  }
```

I Hope it would help.